# Default DateTimeFormatter returns empty string when formatting LocalDateTime in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

The following code returns an empty string:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00.00")
    .format(new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().toFormatter())
```

I'd expect either an exception or the date formatted in some default way.

**Have I found a bug in Java or this is as per specification?** I cannot find any information in Javadoc about this behaviour.

Comment: IMHO a bug because it does not make any sense to construct a temporal formatter without any date or time fields. I don't see a use-case for it, too. Therefore I have prevented users of my time library Time4J to construct such nonsense [formatters](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html) by throwing an exception.

Comment: [***Builder* design pattern**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: It’s very opinion-based. I happen to be happy with the current behaviour, and I believe it agrees with the docs. Not that I don’t understand your objection.

Answer (score 5):

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` is for building a format, it starts off empty. You have to call its various methods such as `appendPattern` to add the format you want.

`DateTimeFormatter` has some standard formats you can use straight off. These use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to build the format. For example:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
static {
    ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00.00").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(""))
```

that produces an empty string in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd expect either exception or the date formatted in some default way

That's your opinion. But IMO, creating an empty builder and add **nothing** to it should result in a - guess what - "empty" formatter - or a formatter with an empty pattern, or whatever.

The documentation doesn't explicity say this will happen, but it also **doesn't say it'll throw an exception or format in some default way**. And if the docs don't say that, so why on earth would you expect that? Based on what?

But the worst thing is thinking that, just because your based-on-nothing expectations weren't satisfied, then it's obviously a bug! Why developers - specially the crappy ones - tend to think *"wow, I found a bug"* when things doesn't go as expected, when most of the time it's their fault?

And why are you creating an empty pattern in the first place?

*"OMG, things didn't happen as I expected, so certainly it's a bug!"*

-- crappy developer

Comment: This doesn't necessarily need to be a bug in the code. There are also bugs in API design or documentation. If API allows to create useless objects then this is issue for me. Same goes for missing pieces of JavaDocs,